# How do I create a multi-level numbered list with OpenOffice Writer?

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-writer

I want to create a multi-level numbered (or bulleted) list with OpenOffice Writer. Eventually, I want to have something like this:

```
1 foo
    1 bar
    2 foobar
2 bar
    1 bork
    2 barfoo
3 huh?
```

I found this surprinsingly hard to do. The first level (1-3) was easy enough, but when I tried to get a second level, OO would either begin from 1 again or keep counting in the second level. I tried this simply using the "Numbering on/off" and "Increase Indent" icons on the toolbar. But the result looked frightening.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start the list as usual and select from Formats->Bullet and Numbering->Outline an appropriate style (I often use the all-numeric 1/1.1/1.1.1 style but there is a 1./1./1./ that should provide the effect you are looking for).

At the end of the first point (default: 1.) press <kbd>enter</kbd>
'2.' will be displayed. If you now press <kbd>tab</kbd> this will change to '1.1'
Complete this point, press <kbd>enter</kbd>, '1.2' will be displayed and so on.

When the last sub-1 point is done, press <kbd>enter</kbd>. Say '1.7' is displayed, press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> and this will change to '2'.

After a bit it all gets obvious and easy. It works the same way for any of the styles and for multiple levels.

Comment: Very nice, thank you! Shift-Tab was the magic key combination I didn't know about.

Comment: in style setting, select 1/1.1/1.1.1 style won't work.

Comment: in style setting, select 1/1.1/1.1.1 style won't work.

Comment: in style setting, select 1/1.1/1.1.1 style won't work.